# Installation of AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, ax, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to install Ax 2012 in my local machine. Does anyone know the steps involved in installing Ax2012

Comment: If you find the answer usefull, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Highlights are you need 64 bit for the AOS, Help Server and EP (if you want it). I agree with the previous answer, 8GB memory is minimum. We tried on 4GB but it just won't work.

Our developers all have 2012 installed on their windows 7 (64 bit) machines. Remember you need SQL reporting installed to run ANY reports. You can run AX 2012 without SQL reporting just fine, but you won't have any reports at all (no invoice and packing slip etc).
Some of our guys have reporting and EP all running on their win7 machines. Remember that that is officially not supported though.

Comment: I have 6Gb memory and it's works fine but if it's 4Gb it'll be very slow.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions in the [Installation Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=12687).

For testing purposes you may use a [preinstalled image](http://palleagermark.blogspot.com/2011/03/run-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-hyper-v.html). Requires PartnerSource or CustomerSource login.

Either option require lots of memory, 8 GB should be a bearable minimum.